# Web API Documentation: /swagger URI just returning JSON on the page and not UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-1.0, swashbuckle

I have added the Swashbuckle libraries to my Web API project to handle API documentation. However, the URI to access this documentation is just displaying JSON object of my swagger options setup.

E.g. `localhost:XXXXX/swagger` redirects to `localhost/XXXXX/swagger/docs/v1`
which then displays the following as opposed to the UI:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"FA.Service.Web.API"},"host":"localhost:xxxxx","schemes":["http"],"paths":{},"definitions":{}}
```

Can anyone tell me why the swagger UI is not displaying for my API?

**SwaggerConfig:**

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    // Get the directory for the XML file.
    protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return System.String.Format(@"{0}\bin\FA.Service.Web.API.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "FA.Service.Web.API");
                c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
                c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.HttpMethod.ToString());

            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
    }
}
```

**Startup:**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

        ConfigureAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        SwaggerConfig.Register();

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you added Swagger, have you used  package manager?

Comment: Yes, I used package manager and added Swashbuckle.WebAPi package

Comment: And do you have valid ApiControllers with methods that are not displayed?

Comment: aahhh that could be it... I thought the framework handled that for us? So you think I need to add a controller and action for the /swagger route?

Comment: Not for the route, but if you don't have ApiControllers, with valid methods (of Get, Post, Put, or Delete), you get exactly what you get now from Swagger. Try it and let me know if this solved the problem.

Comment: oh ok. Yes all API controller actions are annotated with their corresponding Http methods and still no luck.

Comment: Can you please include the code from one of your controllers?

Comment: The default path of the UI is `swagger/ui/index`, not `swagger`.

Comment: `swagger/ui/index` seems to work with regards to showing the page for the UI! However... there is no content in there... it's just showing `[ base url: , api version: v1 ]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the swagger root path in the swaggerConfig.cs